# My app always asks me to open TuneIn Radio when I press Login Facebook button?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have downloaded this morning in trial mode. 
(I didn't connect my Facebook with TuneIn.)

Then, My app cannot login with Facebook anymore :(
It always appears alert popup to open TuneIn Radio

I try to delete TuneIn Radio, so I can login with Facebook.
But, when I installed TuneIn Radio, my app will ask to open TuneIn Radio.

???? What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Same here. Seems those idiots added fbauth2 as a scheme they handle. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to contact TuneIn Radio and tell them to fix their app

Comment: Awesome TuneIn Radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*4/26 Update:* TuneIn v9.7 update fixed the issue.

*Update*: TuneIn replied, acknowledged it's a known issue, and will fix it in an imminent release.

We have users complaining that, too. I can confirm they made the mistake by extracting TuneIn Radio / TuneIn Radio Pro v9.6 ipa file and checking Info.plist inside. I have contacted TuneIn Radio by [sending email with their help center](http://help.tunein.com/customer/portal/emails/new):

> This is a technical issue related to iOS App.
>
> Your URL Scheme contains fbauth2, which makes ANY facebook login redirect to your app, if Facebook iOS SDK in use is prior to v4.6.0. I believe it's a mistake, please update your apps to correct that.

Hope it'll get fixed shortly. Better with Expedited App Review...

For your case, it'll be much simpler by just updating your Facebook iOS SDK to the latest version, so SFSafariViewController will be used for facebook login. Other issues should be fixed, too, I guess.

*4/28 More related update*: The latest update of HERE Maps v1.2.0 just made the same mistake... endless.

Comment: Thanks :) Why is the latest version using web view? Do users have to enter their credentials every time when app request login?

Comment: Nope, SFSafariViewController works essentially like built-in Safari. When users log in with Facebook in SFSafariViewController, Safari is logged in, too.

Comment: Is it the same behaviour as logged in Facebook application?

Comment: No. It's the same behaviour as logged in with Facebook in "iOS built-in Safari". Try it.